# using wslite in grails returning client - Internal Error

Tags: grails, soap, groovy

I have an xml that I am trying to send via wslite to my service.  My service endpoint, lets call it https://development.net/InquiryService

Now when I send the following call through soapUI, I get the correct response

```
<soapenv:Envelope //my header information>
    <soapenv:Header>
       <wsec:Security>
          <wsec:PartnerToken>
             <wsec:PartnerId>xxxx</wsec:PartnerId>
             <wsec:Password>yyyy</wsec:Password>
          </wsec:PartnerToken>
       </wsec:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <acc:retrieveUserAccount>
          <acc:SystemInfo>
             <sys:ServiceContext>
                <sys:transactionId>123</sys:transactionId>
                <sys:sourceLogicalId>zzzz</sys:sourceLogicalId>
             </sys:ServiceContext>
          </acc:SystemInfo>
          <acc:accessRegistration>
             <acc1:userId>xxxx</acc1:userId>
          </acc:accessRegistration>
       </acc:retrieveUserAccount>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I send the service request through grails, using

```
withSoap(serviceURL:"https://development.net/InquiryService"){
    def response = send {
        serviceRequest
    }
}
```

I get `wslite.soap.SOAPFaultException: env:Client - Internal Error`

I have validated the xml is EXACTLY the same, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

I think the issue is I need to add my wsdl somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `serviceRequest` variable is a String, the following should work:

```
def response = send(serviceRequest)
```

The braces are causing it to pass a closure to `send` which if `serviceRequest` is a String you don't want to happen.